# Using a For Loop to Enqueue and Dequeue a Queue - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, queue

I'm working on a lesson involving queues and I'm stuck on the concept of enqueue and dequeue (both boolean functions in a class template for queue) for items that may not be user-input, such as numbers in a file. I've tried running a for loop in order to enqueue certain items onto a queue, for example only placing even integers (from the list 1-10) on a queue:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   if(i % 2 == 0)
      while(intQueue.enqueue(i))
          cout << i << " has been added to the queue . . .\n";
}
```

But for some reason I'm only getting the first item added to the queue on repeat:

```
2 has been added to the queue . . .
2 has been added to the queue . . .
2 has been added to the queue . . .
2 has been added to the queue . . .
2 has been added to the queue . . .
```

I was wondering if I wasn't doing something correctly, or if there's a different way in order to enqueue certain items. Any help or tips is much appreciated.

Comment: remove the `while()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(intQueue.enqueue(i))` will continue to be executed as long as `intQueue.enqueue(i))` returns a value that evaluates to `true`.

What you need to use is `if`.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   if (i % 2 == 0)
   {
      if (intQueue.enqueue(i))
          cout << i << " has been added to the queue . . .\n";
      else
          cout << i << " has not been added to the queue . . .\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: @JosiahHolmes, glad to hear it.

Comment: @JosiahHolmes - If that helped, you should accept the answer